# Prove or disprove $\frac{2^{p}-2}{p}\ \in \Bbb N, \forall\, p,\, prime$

Tags: analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

Apologies in advance for poor formatting, not completely accustomed to typeset. What I ask is any non-particular value $p$, with one condition that it is prime, for which to disprove the following assumption: $$\frac{2^{p}-2}{p}\ \in \Bbb N, \forall\, p,\, prime$$

Since I'm not exactly tech-savvy nor even remotely a mathematician, I can't for the life of me create a simple program to show me its outputs, perhaps someone can help? Also, maybe show with an example that it is true for some composite numbers?
Thank you.

Comment: This is essentially Fermat's Little Theorem: $2^p-2\equiv0\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: You're looking for [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) as others have pointed out. As for a composite moduli $n$, see [Euler's congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Fermat's Theorem, as others have pointed out, a prime $p$ greater than 2 always divides $2^{p-1}-1$. If you multiply that by 2, you get $2^p-2$ is also divisible by $p$, even if it is 2.

Check out [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html) for primes, and a similar theorem, [Euler's Totient Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html) for numbers in general.

Comment: @BarryCipra edited.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
2^p-2=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom pk\equiv0\pmod p
$$
Because $\binom pk$ for $1\le k\le p-1$ is always divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot disprove the statement as this is exactly the Fermat's little theorem.

> For any integer $a$ and prime $p$, $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ i.e. to say $p$ will divide $a^p-a$.

Answer (score 0):

We answer only the last part of your question.  If $q$ is a composite natural number such that $q$ divides $2^q-2$, then $q$ is called a Fermat pseudoprime to the base $2$.

There are infinitely many Fermat pseudoprimes to the base $2$. The smallest is $341$. For a reasonable-sized list, more information,  and references, please see [this OEIS page.](http://oeis.org/A001567)